# Network environment configuration - domain, subdomain, proxy

Tags: networking, server, proxy, domain-server

I'm working on an University project and I don't clearly understand the task I was given.

> 1. Configure network environment with 2 subdomains
> 2. Install SQUID
> 3. Allow access only for chosen subdomain of internal network (using SQUID)
> 4. Reject connections to sites containing e.g. swear words (site content filtering)

The task is not precised, I can realize it in a way I want.

I'm not sure what will be these domains for. As far as I understand, I can configure one domain to e.g. provide me normal connection to sites and second one for connection with filtering. 
SQUID should then block traffic on subdomain1 only allowing connection on second one with site content fitering.

My question is, do I understand it right? 
How these subdomains should look like? I'm not expecting full answer, just some thoughts. I looked over the internet and didn't find anything helpful about subdomains.

Will I need a domain in an internal network which will have two more (sub)domains? What can I use to achieve the result? What a domain really is and what it does?

Thanks for your interest.